# Pass props to component in Unit Test

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a unit test for my app based in Vue and vue-cli with webpack template.

I read Vue documentation, vue-loader, vue-cli and vue-template/webpack (an more!). When I try to make a unit test for my component, I use this.

```
const Constructor = Vue.extend(MyComponent)
vm = new Constructor().$mount()
```

like [Vue-template/webpack example](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/test/unit/specs/Hello.spec.js) and like [Vue official](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html#Writing-Testable-Components)

This work fine. but the pronlem is when my component has some props. I try to pass with this

```
const Constructor = Vue.extend(MyComponent)
vm = new Constructor({
    myprop: 10
}).$mount()
```

And in my unit test, when I try to get this prop, I get undefined. How can I pass prop to my component in unit test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
const Constructor = Vue.extend(MyComponent)
vm = new Constructor({
    propsData: { myprop: 10 }
}).$mount()
```

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#propsData

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do, and what I suggest is to create helper function where you can pass `propsData` to the constructor - It should looks like this:

```
function getComponent(Component, propsData) {
    let Ctor = Vue.extend(Component)
    const el = document.createElement('DIV')
    return new Ctor({propsData, el})
}
```

Usage is pretty easy:

```
describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    const vm = getComponent(MyComponent, {
      propName: 'propValue'
    })
    // expectation
  })
})
```

If you don't have any props you can simply omit the passing second object to helper function

```
describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    const vm = getComponent(MyComponent)
    // expectation
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define your props to option of data and access vueInstance.propName to get value of prop